# Memory leaks in the browser

Tags: javascript, gwt

GWT DOM classes don't support DOM events because the cause memory leaks. Does anybody know which browsers are affected by this problem? And are there any libraries which can help me override this problem?

P.S. I want to use GWT but I want to work with DOM without intermediate level of widgets. If memory leaks are reproducible only in old browsers, I didn't need a workaround since users of the application don't use the old browsers.

Comment: What do you mean "don't support DOM events" they do, it's event listeners that are the problem, but [this link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dom_events_memory_leaks_and_you) should help you with that

Comment: I mean don't support event listeners in a usable way. I just want to be able to add event listeners to an element not some cryptic stuff with sinkEvents and stuff like that.

Comment: Which GWT version are we talking about? As far as I know GWT 2.x has very inteligently resolved many memory leaks. Although you still need to take care and avoid circular references as these are primary source of leaks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, leaks mostly affect IE, but not only.

If you don't want to use widgets, or `sinkEvent`/`addEventListener`, then have a look at GWT-Query: http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#Binding_Events

Comment: But what about memory leaks in gquery?

Comment: I believe events are handled in such a way that they don't leak. GWT Query was started by Ray Cromwell which is now a Google employee working on the GWT team; he's also known for [GWT-Exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) and [Chronoscope](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-chronoscope/), I'm confident that GWT-Query is OK wrt leaks.